# Responsive image scaling

Tags: sapui5

I have 3 images placed into sap.m.FlexBox container which sits in OverlayContainer: [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/mijavivugo/1/edit?html,output)

The problem is that I can't make images in FlexBox to scale to the FlexBox's height.

I need it because when I run my app on PC, tablet or mobile (portrait or landscape layout), I want all images to scale automatically.

How do I do that?

Maybe I should use another layout control, not FlexBox?

Comment: same question here. have you found a solution?